# Android get points of BitMap when I touch on a Image View

Tags: android

When I touch a screen I get the point of screen, My phone is 320 x 240. But I was touching on a ImageView, with a Image with 1024 x 768. How can I get the point of the BitMap?

Sorry, Asked me why the reason of this: Because I need to draw a point over a Image using Canvas, this canvas is in a ImageView, there is a way to put this canvas over the screen?

Comment: did you re-sized the image to fit the width of your screen?

Answer (score 1):

overrirde `onTouchEvent` in your `ImageView`

```
float x, y;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        x = event.getX() + this.getLeft();
        y = event.getY() + this.getTop();
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);

}
```

now x and y have your click position :)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following.

1. Get the x,y when user touches on screen.
2. You already know the x,y from where your imageview starts.
3. With a simple math calculation, you can get the point of bitmap by subtracting the    respective x,y coord.

It is not clear why you want to do this.

Comment: reason of this: Because I need to draw a point over a Image using Canvas, this canvas is in a ImageView.